# What is the HTTP "content-type" to use for a blob of bytes?

Tags: http, http-headers, content-type, pickle

What is the HTTP "content-type" to use when returning a blob of bytes in response to a client's GET request?

In this case, the information payload is an object serialized using Python's [Pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) library.

Comment: Note that everything is a 'blob of bytes', but if there's indeed to known mimetype, `application/octet-stream` is a good pick.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You should use `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: Or, alternatively, not send a Content-Type header field at all.

Answer (score 6):

You should use the proper MIME type:

```
application/python-pickle
```

This is the de-facto standard (this mean: it is not application/pickle or application/pickle-python).

RFC2046 states:

***4.5.3. Other Application Subtypes** It is expected that many other subtypes of "application" will be defined in the future. MIME implementations must at a minimum treat any unrecognized subtypes as being equivalent to "application/octet- stream".*

So, to a non-pickle-aware system, the stream will look like any other octet-stream (you are not doing anything which will break existing apps), but to a pickle-aware system this is vital information.

Comment: That's not the "proper" type (it's not in the registry)

Comment: It is the de-facto standard. RFC2046 states: 4.5.3.  Other Application Subtypes

   It is expected that many other subtypes of "application" will be
   defined in the future.  MIME implementations must at a minimum treat
   any unrecognized subtypes as being equivalent to "application/octet-
   stream". So, to a non-pickle-aware system, the stream will look like any other octet-stream, but for a pickle-enabled system this is vital information

Comment: Can you provide references for "This is the de-facto standard" ?

Answer (score 0):

To pass a bytes object from Angular to Django, removing the `content-type` from headers works as well, i.e.

```
const httpOptions =  {headers: new HttpHeaders({})}
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file);
this.http.post(myAPI(), formData, httpOptions).subscribe(
```

where `file` is a bytes object e.g. a (pickle) file uploaded by user.

Using `application/octet-stream` might throw a `415 Unsupported media Type in http.post Angular request` error.