# Preferred (or most common) file extension for a Python pickle

Tags: python, rest, filenames, mime-types, pickle

At times, I've seen `.pickle`, `.pck`, `.pcl`, and `.db` for files that contain Python pickles, but I am unsure what is the most common or best practice. I know that the latter three extensions are also used for other things.

The related question is: What MIME type is preferred for sending pickles between systems using a REST API?

Comment: What's funny is that I'm sure once upon a time I've used .pkl.

Comment: For some reason this is not in the Python 3 doc, but in the Python 2 doc and specifying `pkl` -> https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#example

Comment: Avoid pickle wherever possible. There's a reason the docs warn against using pickle - it's not safe, it's never been safe, and it never will be safe.

Use the json module instead.

Comment: @KingRadical could you give some alternatives?

Comment: @RafaNogales msgpack seems a good binary alternative https://pypi.org/project/u-msgpack-python/

Answer (score 160, accepted):

**Python 2**

From the [Python 2 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#example), while serializing (i.e. writing to a pickle file), use:

```
output = open('data.pkl', 'wb')
```

I would choose `.pkl` as the extension when using Python 2.

**Python 3**

The example in the [Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pickle.html#examples) now uses `.pickle` as the file extension for serialization:

```
with open('data.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(...)
```

---

The MIME type preferred for sending pickles from [martineau's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40433474/preferred-or-most-common-file-extension-for-a-python-pickle/40433504#comment68116195_40433504) below:

> application/octet-stream

See *[What is the HTTP "content-type" to use for a blob of bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223855/what-is-the-http-content-type-to-use-for-a-blob-of-bytes)*

Comment: `text/plain` might not work depending on the pickle protocol being used — protocol version 0 is the only one that's ASCII.

Comment: That said, I think `application/octet-stream` would be better regardless of the protocol — see question [_What is the HTTP “content-type” to use for a blob of bytes?_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223855/what-is-the-http-content-type-to-use-for-a-blob-of-bytes)